# Lilypond does not propperly render Chords when used with --png

Tags: lilypond

I'm truing to compile a `lilypond` score with the `--png` option. For some reason the chords do not get compiled properly when using this option. Running `lilypond` without the `--png` option works fine. [The `PDF` file](http://lilybin.com/9sqic1/1) comes out as as expected, only the `PNG` file looks like this:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
\version "2.18.2"

#(set-global-staff-size 30)
\include "lilypond-book-preamble.ly"

\paper {
  ragged-last = ##f
}

\header {
  title = "Title"
  subtitle = \markup { \null }
  tagline = ##f
}

\score {
  <<
    \new ChordNames \chordmode { c1 d1:m e1:m f1 }
      { \set chordChanges = ##t } 
    \new Staff { \relative c' { c1 d e f }}
    \addlyrics { \lyricmode { \tiny good mor -- ning all. }}
  >>
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```

Some System INFOS:

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
            Kernel: Linux 4.13.0-1-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
  Lilypond Version: 2.18.2-11`

       Ghostscript: 9.22~dfsg-1
```

I tried to compile with different fonts, by adding:

```
\paper  {
  #(define fonts
    (make-pango-font-tree "Times New Roman"
                          "Nimbus Sans"
                          "Luxi Mono"
                          (/ staff-height pt 20)))
}
```

`PDF` output again works fine, `--png` output looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a problem rather related to `ghostscript` then `lilypond`

Using `Century Schoolbook L` instead of `Times New Roman`:

```
\paper  {
  #(define fonts
    (make-pango-font-tree "Century Schoolbook L"
                          "Nimbus Sans"
                          "Luxi Mono"
                          (/ staff-height pt 20)))
}
```

finally worked:

[image]

Thanks again to the support from Channel: [#lilypond on Freenode!](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=lilypond)